# Error when parsing body of an HTTP request using Python Request lib

Tags: python, python-requests, postman, httprequest

I have tested some requests inside the Postman app. First, I want to get the body information of an HTTP request inside Python (package requests used). The response appears positive with 200 OK.

```
response = session.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify ='custom-proxy-ca.crt')
```

Now I would like to get the body with

```
body = response.content
```

`Print(body)` delivers

```
b'\x83\x84\x01\x00\xc4\xff\xd4\xe9\xb4\xf6\xde,\x13\xa9\xc0(\xc7_\x8dL\x90\xf0\xb4K\xc4<\xe7\xb1M\x02)\xe0\x80z\xd0\xdf>\xcf\xd7\xd2\xec\x8d\x1e\xe4un\x0c\x83\xa1\x88g\xe7fah\x89\xbe\xca\xa8\x04_\xa2W\xbd\xfe]W\xd1\x06\x1f\xef~ZN\xa6\x0bq\xfa\x18\xc4\x1f\xb3\xf8\xc2\x9dF\xc5\xf0\xe6\x8d\xb6\xc1\xa0\xab\x7f\xfbyM\xe0\x88I\xb4\xd4\x82\xa1%\xd9R7Nt\xa4~<\x8c\x8e\xdb\xe7<xx-.\xab\xa7|16\xcb"\xba\x89\xbc\xe7\xcaF\xd1\xacV-u\xbf\xaa\x04\xf7\xa2\x88\xa1\x1bUI\xdfkI$`\x18:j\x7fU\x02\x0e\xcb\x97\x8em\xc6\x81\xe6\x85\xbe\xa5\xb9vbjQ$}M&n\xe0$A\xe0\xd9\xd2\xc6\x9aA\xf4\x12\x81/1\x0c\xf0(\x0cy\xf5\xaf\xca\x1bQ\x1082\xa1\xb4n4VRR\xbb7\xa5XO\x08\x0c\x13\xf2:\xc0-\x06\xa9\xda\xaeGX\x97B\x81!\x17\x87\xfa\xd1\x1b\xc0\xd0\x89|\xe8E\x0f\rp\xfd\x00\x96\xeaI\xbe\xda\xbb\xe3\x87\xc7\xdb\x9b\xfd\xab\xe8\xc7\xdd\x0cEL-x\xe0\x9bVhY\x0cT\x08\x95S\xa3\xfd\xdc\xe3\x81/1\x9d\x9e\'T\xf6\xe0pl\xd33#0,T}X%\x04\x0e\xd7r\xfd\x10\x0cs\xe90\x05\xe8\xe8\xf8\xea\xfc\xe5\xf8\xe1\xfd\xb9\xea\xe7\xe0\xc0\x9a!\xa1\\M\xa8\x9d\x9f\xe4\xa2\x07_\xae\xd7\x0c\xdd\xb8\xaa\xbf\xe9\xfc\x1a|\x89^\xf59\x81\xe3J\x91\xa4v(\xff7J1\x1ao\x9c\x89\xa1#0\xf4\xaa\xa0\xc7\xbc\xea\x9f\xae\xa6\xe8\xa9-T\xc9#\xd1\x81\x7f\xee\x9a\xbb\xfd\x87\xc3\xe3+|K\xe2\xfdPe\xa0\xaa\x9d\x18\xf0\xcc\xc0\xf10\x80\xca\xb0XuW\x9d\xcc\xc0\xa5\xc8;bP\xdd\x9d\x1aeC\xfd\xf84\xa6\x14yG\xeb\xb5\x01\x03'
```

Now I try to search a token in the body, but it seems to be encrypted.
If I want to get the result of the JSON parser with
`json.loads(body)`
it returns
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: invalid start byte`.
Okay, it seems that the encoding is done in a different way than expected. But how did the Postman app do the decoding of the body? For example, I can read it there parsed as JSON (see the figure below). What am I doing wrong in Python?

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L5iB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is solved, but I want to share with you how to deal with this kind of problem.

The initial problem is to call the HTTP POST request with the header parameter `Accept-Encoding` like

```
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
```

This line of code means: Locally can receive data in compressed format.
The server compresses the large file and sends it back to the client during processing. After receiving the IE, the IE performs a local pressure on the file.
The reason for the error is: the program did not extract the file

Solution: delete this line of code and it works